# How to configure P4Ant Tasks to use ssl port

Tags: ant, perforce, p4java

We use a few [P4Ant tasks](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4ant/p4tasks.html) to commit code to our perforce depots from within an Ant task. This has been working fine for months, however we recently changed our perforce server to only accept trusted/ssl connections.

As such, our new P4 port now looks like `ssl:server_hostname:port` and we’re getting an error when running our Ant task: `non-numeric Perforce server port specifier: p4java://ssl:server_hostname:port` .

From the [P4Java api](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4java/01_p4java.html#1076164) (which P4Ant uses under the hood), it seems that the connection should have looked like: `p4javassl://server_hostname:port`

Does the `P4Ant` library support SSL perforce ports? If so, how can I configure it to pass this port properly to `p4java`.

Comment: I see you have already contacted Perforce support regarding this issue and are receiving assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding P4Ant and SSL, not as downloaded because it is bundled with a pre-2012.1 P4Java version.  SSL support was added for P4Java versions 2012.1 and forward as noted in the release notes:

```
http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/p4javanotes.txt
```

It should work by using (replacing) the p4java.jar with the latest version.

See the following Knowledge Base article:

```
http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/P4Ant--SSL-p4d
```

Also, you can check this article regarding your java installation in case you may also need the following:

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Using-P4Java-and-P4Eclipse-with-SSL-enabled-Perforce-Servers